# Tabs switched to empty while typing in a textfield

Tags: reactjs, electron, material-ui

There are three tab A, B, C in a tabs component. Type a character into TextField which is in tab C's form. Suddenly tabs switched to empty, without selecting any tab.

deps:

    `"material-ui": "^0.15.0-alpha.1",
    "react": "*",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.2"
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.0"`

```
//setting.jsx
'use babel';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import TextField from 'material-ui/lib/text-field';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/lib/raised-button';

var Settings = React.createClass({
    render(){
        return (
            <form>
                <TextField
                    hintText="username"
                    floatingLabelText="please enter username"
                    type="text"
                />
                <TextField
                    hintText="password"
                    floatingLabelText="please enter password"
                    type="text"
                />
                <RaisedButton type="submit" label="login" className="button-submit" primary={true} />
            </form>
        );
    }
});

export default Settings;

//TabNav.jsx
'use babel';

import fs from 'fs';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Tabs from 'material-ui/lib/tabs/tabs';
import Tab from 'material-ui/lib/tabs/tab';
import FontIcon from 'material-ui/lib/font-icon';

import Settings from '../views/Settings.jsx';
import Timetable from '../views/Timetable.jsx';
import Notes from '../views/Notes.jsx';

class TabNav extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: 'timetable'
        };
        this.CourseJsonData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/courses.json', 'utf8'));
    }

    handleChange = (value) => {
        this.setState({
            value: value
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Tabs value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <Tab value="timetable" icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">view_list</FontIcon>}>
                    <Timetable data={this.CourseJsonData}/>
                </Tab>
                <Tab value="notes" icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">assignment_turned_in</FontIcon>}>
                    <Notes/>
                </Tab>
                <Tab value="settings" icon={<FontIcon className="material-icons">settings</FontIcon>}>
                    <Settings/>
                </Tab>
            </Tabs>
        );
    }
}

export default TabNav;
```

[before-entering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3h39.png)

Then press any key once.

[after-entering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rgmc.png)

Comment: We need code, we need way more code

Comment: @ZekeDroid Already added.

Comment: What do you mean "tabs switched to empty"?

Comment: @ZekeDroid Added a couple of illustrative pictures. Please look at the pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a material-ui bug:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/2189

The workaround is to add onChange handlers to your text inputs:

```
            <TextField
                hintText="username"
                floatingLabelText="please enter username"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation();}}
            />
            <TextField
                hintText="password"
                floatingLabelText="please enter password"
                type="text"
                onChange={(e)=>{e.stopPropagation();}}
```